# Is it possible to use Convert.ToInt32(double) and make it choose the smallest value?

Tags: c#, double, int32

Is it possible to use Convert.ToInt32(double) and make it choose the smallest value?

I've read the examples in msdn, it converts a double to int using the closest value, which means that if i have a double equal to 2.9 it would set the int to 3.

Is it possible to use convert.toint32 and use 2?

Comment: maybe you can try casting: `(int)yournumber`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Math.Floor.  See this link:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor(v=vs.110).aspx

EDIT:  Math.Floor returns a double, so you will have to cast it, such as int y = (int)Math.Floor(3.934333), which would return 3.

Comment: I tried that before, but the math.floor didn't work, exactly because it returns a double and i need a int. What's the point of having a double "floored"?

Comment: You just cast the return of math.floor to an int.

Answer (score 3):

You can use just casting to int, you can check it:

```
double x = 2.9;
int y = (int) x;
Console.WriteLine (y); // 2
```

Comment: @ng80092b casting to int truncates the number, not rounds, this answer is correct.